# IF Statements with AND and N/A calculations

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum, sumifs

I hope you can help. I have a couple of formulas that are breaking due to N/A appearing in cells. I was wondering if these N/A could be accommodated in my formulas to still return a numerical result.
In the picture below you can see that in Cell C21 there is 'N/A' and in S21 the is the error #VALUE! The reason for this error is of course because of the 'N/A'

Can the formula in S21 be amended to factor in this 'N/A' and return a number even if it is present. My formula is below

```
=SUM(AND(C21>=12,C21<=19)*C21,AND(F21>=2,F21<=20)*F21,AND(I21>=2,I21<=20)*I21,AND(L21>=2,L21<=20)*L21)
```

Here is the picture of the spreadsheet

[image]

Comment: Iferror function https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611?CorrelationId=1da17c3a-b708-4820-9942-a38a8b6ca311&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Thank you to the two guys Tristanto and Brian they really helped get to this answer so the formula that works to solve this puzzle is below. I hope it helps

```
=SUM(IF(C21="N/A",0,AND(C21>=12,C21<=19)*C21),IF(F21="N/A",0,AND(F21>=2,F21<=20)*F21),IF(I21="N/A",0,AND(I21>=2,I21<=20)*I21),IF(L21="N/A",0,AND(L21>=2,L21<=20)*L21))
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but give this a try. You can change the value of zero to whatever you want:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(AND(C21>=12,C21<=19)*C21,AND(F21>=2,F21<=20)*F21,
AND(I21>=2,I21<=20)*I21,AND(L21>=2,L21<=20)*L21),0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately it is not working. I get a new error which is #NAME? Is there another way?

Comment: I tried with IFNA but IFERROR should work as noted above. See edit!

Comment: @ Brian: The formula you gave me returns a 0. Even though there are other numbers present. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: What number are you wanting to return? If `S1` is both a dependent value and an error how can you get anything else?

Comment: @ Brian: Thank you for the help, but i got it to work with the below `=SUM(IF(C21="N/A",0,AND(C21>=12,C21<=19)*C21),IF(F21="N/A",0,AND(F21>=2,F21<=20)*F21),IF(I21="N/A",0,AND(I21>=2,I21<=20)*I21),IF(L21="N/A",0,AND(L21>=2,L21<=20)*L21))`

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(ISNA(C21),0,SUM(AND(C21>=12,C21<=19)*C21,AND(F21>=2,F21<=20)*F21,AND(I21>=2,I21<=20)*I21,AND(L21>=2,L21<=20)*L21)) <br>
```

If cell C21 is N/A cell S21 will 0. You can replace 0 with other number or text.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately it is not working I get the same error. Is there another way?

Comment: Probably ISNA doesn't work in your excel. Please try =ISNA(C21) in a cell! Does it return "TRUE" Or "FALSE"?

Comment: =ISNA(C21) returns FALSE. Thank you again for the help.